# when selecting one option in radio buttons group, display some info and make sums of selected items

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm tring to build a sort of web based pricelist for the company where i work, I'll post the  `$scope.model = '';` [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5GLgWw7zehUFiWxRuAX5?p=preview) of the work I'm doing what i want to achieve is when a person select one option in the radio buttons group i want to display some info and make sums of the selected items, the other thing i want to reach is to enable the radio buttons groups only if the previous is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest writing an `onChange` function which is then fired each time a button is pressed. This `onChange` function should read the values of all the currently selected buttons and then you can manipulate them as you need (add them etc).

To achieve this you will probably want to convert your buttons from `label` to `input`, or give your `label` a hidden input which stores the currently selected value.

Answer (score 0):

Here I Created one jsfiddle according for your need. Here I have one Array of element and I bind this in HTML page.

```
<div ng-app="">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <label data-ng-repeat="choice in amountList.choices">
  <input type="radio" name="response" data-ng-model="price" data-ng-value="true" ng-change="FirstListSelect(choice)" />
  {{choice.price}}
</label>
<div>
<label data-ng-repeat="choice in amountList.choices">
  <input type="radio" name="response2" data-ng-model="price2" data-ng-value="true" ng-change="SecondListSelect(choice)" />
  {{choice.price}}
</label>
</div>

  <br/>

{{total}}
  </div>
</div>
```

And I had done some code into Js file :-

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

  $scope.FirstListvalue=0;
  $scope.SecondListvalue=0;
  $scope.total=0;
  $scope.amountList = {
    choices: [{
            id: 1,
            price: 500
        }, {
            id: 2,
            price: 600
        }, {
            id: 3,
            price: 500
        }]
}; 
$scope.FirstListSelect=function(data)
{
alert(data.price);
$scope.FistListvalue=data.price;
if($scope.SecondListvalue!=null)
{
$scope.total=data.price+$scope.SecondListvalue;
}
else
{
$scope.total=data.price;
}
};

$scope.SecondListSelect=function(data)
{
alert(data.id);
$scope.SecondListvalue=data.price
if($scope.FistListvalue!=null)
{
$scope.total=data.price+$scope.FistListvalue;
}
else
{
$scope.total=data.price;
}
};
}
```

Following working example I created :- http://jsfiddle.net/kpsingh/LXAt7/503/

Comment: Hi,tank you for your answer, the problem is that the radio buttons groups is variable is not alwais the same.

Comment: but the example you posted after some clicks stop to work's